# Linux: where to install/unpack programs manually

Tags: linux

Where to unpack programs in **Linux** e.g. Tomcat binary?

Is there a common location as in Windows, i.e. **Program Files**...
which won't be overwritten during Linux upgrade.

Is it a good approach to unpack it in, let's say: **/home/user/PRG** location. 
Thanx!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several places to put third party software, it's really up to you, but preferably:

```
/opt
```

as the name implies 'optional packages' - so tomcat could go in /opt/tomcat

Or for single file applications such as scripts etc., go for

```
/usr/local
```

Comment: This seems most logical location for me. Thanx

Comment: I had some problems using /opt, e.g. PyCharm can't update itself because it doesn't have write permissions in /opt. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For things like tomcat, you might want to put it under /usr/local may be or /usr/share directory. thats where things generally gets installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes /usr/local is the folder for installing tomcat. Detailed steps are available at http://justin-hayes.com/2009-04-08/installing-apache-tomcat-6-and-solr-nightly-on-ubuntu-804